# proof: maximum likelihood and least square is pseudo-inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, machine-learning, mean-square-error

Why does does the following gradient equal transpose of phi?

$\nabla_w \bigg[w^T\phi\bigg] = \phi^T$

instead of just phi?

$\nabla_w \bigg[w^T\phi\bigg] = \phi$

---

as in minimizing sum-of-squares error problem..

$$\ln p(t|w, \beta) = \prod^{N}_{n=1} \ln \Bigg[ \bigg( \frac{1}{(2\pi\sigma^2)^{1/2}}\bigg)exp\bigg( \frac{-1}{2\sigma^2}(t_n-\mu)^2 \bigg) \Bigg]$$

$$\ln p(t|w, \beta) = \sum^{N}_{n=1} \bigg[ \frac{-1}{2}\ln(2\pi\sigma^2) + \frac{-1}{2\sigma^2}(t_n-\mu)^2 \bigg]$$

$$\ln p(t|w, \beta) = \sum^{N}_{n=1} \bigg[ \frac{-1}{2\sigma^2}(t_n-\mu)^2 + \frac{-1}{2}\ln(2\pi\sigma^2)\bigg]$$

$$\ln p(t|w, \beta) = \frac{-1}{2\sigma^2} \sum^{N}_{n=1} \bigg[ (t_n-\mu)^2 \bigg] + \frac{-N}{2}\ln(2\pi\sigma^2)$$

$$\ln p(t|w, \beta) = -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum^{N}_{n=1} \bigg[ (t_n-\mu)^2 \bigg] - \frac{N}{2}ln(\sigma^2) - \frac{N}{2}\ln(2\pi)$$

$$\ln p(t|w, \beta) = -\beta \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\sum^{N}_{n=1} (t_n-w^T\phi(x_n))^2 \bigg) + \frac{N}{2}ln(\beta) - \frac{N}{2}\ln(2\pi)$$

$$E(w) = \frac{1}{2}\sum^{N}_{n=1} (t_n-w^T\phi(x_n))^2$$

$$\ln p(t|w, \beta) = -\beta  E(w) + \frac{N}{2}ln(\beta) - \frac{N}{2}\ln(2\pi)$$

Now, I want to maximize the probability with respect to weighting coefficients w.   To do this we take the Gradient with respect to w, and then find the value of w when the gradient is zero,  this will maximize the probability or likelihood.

$$\nabla_w \bigg( -\beta  E(w) + \frac{N}{2}ln(\beta) - \frac{N}{2}\ln(2\pi) \bigg) = 0$$

$$-\beta~\nabla_w E(w) = 0 $$

$$-\frac{\beta}{2}\sum^{N}_{n=1} \nabla_w \bigg((t_n-w^T\phi(x_n))^2 \bigg)=0$$

$$\beta\sum^{N}_{n=1} \nabla_w \bigg((t_n-w^T\phi(x_n))^2 \bigg)=0$$

$$\beta\sum^{N}_{n=1} 2(t_n-w^T\phi(x_n)) \nabla_w \bigg(t_n-w^T\phi(x_n) \bigg) =0$$

$$\beta\sum^{N}_{n=1} (t_n-w^T\phi(x_n)) \nabla_w \bigg(w^T\phi(x_n) \bigg) =0$$

Here's where i get confused....book say result should be:

$$\beta\sum^{N}_{n=1} (t_n-w^T\phi(x_n)) \ \phi(x_n)^T = 0$$

how do you know the gradient in previous step should add a transpose to the result?

$$\beta\sum^{N}_{n=1} \bigg(t_n\phi(x_n)^T-w^T\phi(x_n)\phi(x_n)^T \bigg) =0$$

$$\sum^{N}_{n=1} \bigg(t_n\phi(x_n)^T-w^T\phi(x_n)\phi(x_n)^T \bigg) =0$$

$$\bigg(\sum^{N}_{n=1} t_n\phi(x_n)^T\bigg) - w^T \bigg( \sum^{N}_{n=1} \phi(x_n)\phi(x_n)^T \bigg) =0$$

not sure about this step.... but should equal this:

$$\phi^T t = w (\phi^T \phi)$$

$$w_{ML}=(\phi^T \phi)^{-1} \phi^T t$$

Comment: Probably just a convention; in the world of mathematics, vectors are just families of numbers, hence "column" or "row" vector are just conventions.

Comment: I was wondering if there's a secret table of vector derivative somewhere that they never give you.... I could almost make up a rule about it... and add it to my table... but better to get it from the source...

Comment: What does $\nabla_w$ stand for? If we're talking about the *gradient* with respect to the $w$ variable, the gradient should be a vector, and so the answer should be $\phi$. If we're talking about the *derivative*, the answer should be a linear map, and so the answer should be $\phi^\top$.

Comment: Matrix Calculus by Magnus.

Comment: https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~schmidtm/Courses/Notes/linearQuadraticGradients.pdf  just not the one i'm looking for....

Comment: looks like a good book...i'll order a copy...

Comment: is it fair to say that since the inner product is a scalar if your differentiate an inner product with respect to one of its vectors, then its completely ambiguous if the result is row or column vector?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Wikipedia article: matrix calculus, taking a vector derivative of a scalar is a row vector:

---

**from wikipedia**:

The derivative of a scalar y by a vector

$$\mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix}
    x_1 &
    x_2 &
    \cdots &
    x_n
  \end{bmatrix}^\mathsf{T}$$

is written as

$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial \mathbf{x}} =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{\partial y}{\partial x_1} &
    \frac{\partial y}{\partial x_2} &
    \cdots &
    \frac{\partial y}{\partial x_n}
  \end{bmatrix}.
$$

---

**thus**:

$$\mathbf{\phi} = \begin{bmatrix}
    \phi_1 &
    \phi_2 &
    \cdots &
    \phi_n
  \end{bmatrix}^\mathsf{T}$$

$\frac{\partial}{\partial w} \bigg[w^T\phi\bigg] = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial}{\partial w_1} w_1 \phi_1 & \frac{\partial}{\partial w_2} w_2 \phi_2 & ... & \frac{\partial}{\partial w_n} w_n \phi_n   \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\phi_1 & \phi_2 & ... & \phi_n \end{bmatrix} = \phi^T$

Answer (score 0):

abuse of notation because a gradient requires a function with scalar parameters...

its really taking a partial derivative with respect to tensor $w_i$.

change:

$\nabla_w \bigg[w^T\phi\bigg]$

to:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial w_i} \bigg[w^T\phi\bigg]$

Then we can convert inner product to tensor notation

$\frac{\partial}{\partial w_i} \bigg[w_j \phi_j \bigg] = \frac{\partial}{\partial w_i}  \bigg[w_j  \bigg]\phi_j = \delta_{ij} \phi_j = \phi_i$

---

change:

$\beta\sum^{N}_{n=1} (t_n-w^T\phi(x_n)) \nabla_w \bigg(w^T\phi(x_n) \bigg) =0$

to:

$\beta\sum^{N}_{n=1} (t_n-w^T\phi(x_n)) \frac{\partial}{\partial w_i} \bigg(w^T\phi(x_n) \bigg) =0$

$\beta\sum^{N}_{n=1} (t_n-w^T\phi(x_n)) \phi_i(x_n) =0$

So now I have equations i=1 to n:

$\beta\sum^{N}_{n=1} (t_n-w^T\phi(x_n)) \phi_1(x_n) =0$

$\beta\sum^{N}_{n=1} (t_n-w^T\phi(x_n)) \phi_2(x_n) =0$

$...$

$\beta\sum^{N}_{n=1} (t_n-w^T\phi(x_n)) \phi_n(x_n) =0$

converting tensor $\phi_i$ back to a vector form...(why its a row or column at this point i have no idea...)  now $\phi^T$ is a row vector:

$\beta\sum^{N}_{n=1} (t_n-w^T\phi(x_n)) \phi^T(x_n) =0$